# Creating multiple similar genrules and using their output

Tags: bazel

I have a genrule that looks like the below. It basically runs a simple go template tool that gets a resource name, a json file and template and outputs the rendered file. I have a bunch of resources that all need to be in separate files and ultimately packaged into a container.

```
resources = ["foo", "bar"]
[genrule(
    name = "generate_" + resource + "_config",
    srcs = [
        "//some:tool:config.tmpl",
        "//some:json",
    ],
    outs = [resource + ".hcl"],
    cmd = "$(location //some/tool:template) -resource " + resource + " -json_path=$(location //some:json) -template=$(location //some/tool:config.tmpl) -out=$@",
    tools = [
        "/some/tool:template",
    ],
) for resource in resources]
```

The above will generate a few rules named `generate_foo_config` and `generate_bar_config` and the files output correctly. I however cannot figure out how to use each one without specifying them directly in a filegroup or pkg_tar rule without enumerating each one. I would like to be able to add a new thing to the resources variable, and have it automatically included in the filegroup or tar for use in a build rule later. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), like you've got creating the genrules. Something like this:

```py
pkg_tar(
    name = "all_resources",
    srcs = [":generate_" + resource + "_config" for resource in resources],
)
```

You can also put the list in a variable in the BUILD file to use it multiple times:

```py
all_resources = [":generate_" + resource + "_config" for resource in resources]
pkg_tar(
    name = "all_resources",
    srcs = all_resources,
)
filegroup(
    name = "resources_filegroup",
    srcs = all_resources,
)
```